# VS Code Keybinding Command to create a new PYTHON file

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I had `Ctrl+N Ctrl+P` bound to the command `Python:createNewFile` but it stopped working after a recent VSCode update (I believe, not sure if it was something else).

Does anyone know the VSCode key binding command to create a new Python file?

`Ctrl+N` gets me a new text file and I have to select the language or save it with .py for it to be a python file, which is cumbersome since I mostly use VSCode only for python.

Comment: Does adding `"files.defaultLanguage": "python"` to the `settings.json` file give you the expected behavior?

Comment: which extension implements `Python:createNewFile`

Comment: The default extension - there are still a lot of `python.` commands available - just not that one.

Comment: @mahieyin-rahmun Thank you and yes it works but that just forces every new file to a python file, even when I use the File menu and select new text file. Is there a way to tie this to a specific key binding?

Comment: I'm in the same situation, after the update, VSCode shows that command 'python.createNewFile' not found, so I think it was replaced or deleted...